# create one table from a csv file with multiple tables (that have vertical table info above each)

Tags: r, csv

I need salinity/temperature data from the NDBC. I have managed to download it but in the csv file there is a table for each buoy containing data for various depths (I only want the shallowest depth) with info like lat/long coordinates and the time/day/month/year above each buoy in a vertical table.

Is there anyway to create one table with the date/time, coordinates, temp and salinity data of each buoy?

a code for r or any other language (except VBA as the file is too large for excel!)

Thanks in advance!!

Below is a copy of the first two buoys:

```
Latitude                    ,,        25.5590,decimal degrees,,
Longitude                   ,,       -66.0020,decimal degrees,,
Year                        ,,           2003,,,
Month                       ,,             11,,,
Day                         ,,              3,,,
Time                        ,,           2.97,decimal hours (UT),,
VARIABLES ,Depth     ,F,O,Temperatur ,F,O,Salinity   ,F,O,Oxygen     ,F,O,,
UNITS     ,m         , , ,degrees C ,, , ,PSS       ,, , ,ml/l      ,, , ,,
Prof-Flag ,          ,0, ,          ,0, ,          ,0, ,          ,0, ,,
         1,      2.58,0,2,   27.4173,0,2,   36.5551,0,2,     4.577,0,2,
         2,     23.64,0,2,   27.4678,0,2,   36.6834,0,2,     4.581,0,2,


----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Latitude                    ,,        26.2110,decimal degrees,,
Longitude                   ,,       -66.0072,decimal degrees,,
Year                        ,,           2003,,,
Month                       ,,             11,,,
Day                         ,,              3,,,
Time                        ,,           10.0,decimal hours (UT),,
VARIABLES ,Depth     ,F,O,Temperatur ,F,O,Salinity   ,F,O,Oxygen     ,F,O,,
UNITS     ,m         , , ,degrees C ,, , ,PSS       ,, , ,ml/l      ,, , ,,
Prof-Flag ,          ,0, ,          ,0, ,          ,0, ,          ,0, ,,
         1,      3.18,0,2,   27.5938,0,2,   36.8218,0,2,     4.563,0,2,
         2,     25.33,0,2,   27.6006,0,2,   36.8357,0,2,     4.554,0,2,
```

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example and format it correctly using SO formating options?

Comment: Hi Luke, does this help? not quite sure how to show it best!

Comment: Have you tried something from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+read+NDBC)? Looks like a painful task to parse. Where exactly did you download those two (urls)?